# Color a Point Cloud- Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst, point-clouds, ply

I have a ply image. I want to color it according to my requirement. 
1. (.ply) image from kinect
2. Change the rgb value of all point in cloud

e.g

.ply image where all points in the cloud are to be in yellow or blue color.
 I have been able to display it using Matlab command "scatter3" but also want to save the colored point cloud as a new point cloud by "pcwrite" function of Matlab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer properly to this question I should know which version of Matlab are you using. If you are using Matlab 2015a you should have these three function

- pcread to read a 3D point cloud (.ply file);
- pcshow to show a 3D point cloud;
- pcwrite to write a .ply file.

Let's say your image is called "airplane.ply".
To properly use that you first read the image using:

```
ptCloud = pcread('airplane.ply')
```

then you will notice that ptCloud has different field. One of that regard the color, and is the one you have to change. To do so you have to specify a colour for each point in the cloud. So:

```
pointscolor=uint8(zeros(ptCloud.Count,3));
pointscolor(:,1)=255;
pointscolor(:,2)=255;
pointscolor(:,3)=51;
```

since [255 255 51] is the yellow color.
Then assign this matrix to the ptCloud.Color.

```
ptCloud.Color=pointscolor;
```

See the result:

```
pcshow(ptCloud)
```

and save the file:

```
pcwrite(ptCloud,'ptCloud.ply')
```

where 'ptCloud.ply' is the name you want to assign to the file.